# Does the functor of Chevalley–Eilenberg cochains $ CE^\bullet:L_\infty\mathbf{Alg}^{op}\to \mathbf{dgAlg} $ map homotopy limits to homotopy colimits?

Tags: model-categories, higher-algebra

I was wondering whether the functor of Chevalley–Eilenberg cochains
$$
\operatorname{CE}^\bullet:L_\infty\mathbf{Alg}^\text{op}\to \mathbf{dgAlg}
$$
maps homotopy limits to homotopy colimits. Is still well known, or obviously false?

Comment: Hi Nicola,  there are probably finiteness issues but modulo those the answer will depend on whether your target is dg algebras or commutative dg algebras  (no in the former, and yes in the latter).

Comment: Of course CE lands in cdga, I mean this target. Do you have a reference for the statement here?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't and there will be finiteness issues that I (as an amateur) don't know how to handle.  But the idea is that CE is approximately an equivalence  (or is an equivalence, depending on what your notion of weak-equivalence on either side is).

Comment: For finite limits, one strategy is to verify that homotopy fiber products get sent to homotopy pushouts:  homotopy fiber products are given by  homotopy fiber products of underlying chain complexes (i.e. cones),  and you can see that CE takes cones to derived tensor products using  Sym(g_1 \oplus g_2) \iso Sym(g_1) \otimes Sym(g_2).

Comment: Thanks, @user1092847. I was thinking that if this is true it should be well known, and a consequence of some abstract non-sense.  Because (let's say in cochains) CE is the homotopy representable (?? whatever this is) of \R in pointed moduli spaces. But I'm unsure about the precise argument here.

Comment: I don't think the claim is true. Given a finite-dimensional abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ consider the finite limit $\mathfrak{g}[-1] = 0\oplus_{\mathfrak{g}} 0$. Then $\mathrm{CE}(\mathfrak{g}[-1]) = \widehat{\mathrm{Sym}}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$. But $k\otimes_{\mathrm{CE}(\mathfrak{g})} k\cong \mathrm{Sym}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$. The same problem arises with sums: $\mathrm{CE}(k[-1]\oplus k[-1])\not\cong\mathrm{CE}(k[-1])\otimes\mathrm{CE}(k[-1])$. The representability claim you mentioned is related to the fact that $\mathrm{CE}$ takes colimits in $L_\infty$ algebras to limits in cdgas.